# Insert date value in Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I'm trying to insert a date value in a MySQL table like this (using Laravel 5.1):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);      
  $data = $request->all();         
  $data['birthdate'] = date("Y-d-m", strtotime($data['birthdate']));
  ...
  $user->fill($data)->save();
```

It works fine if I insert a date which the day < 12, while it'll be inserted 1970-01-01 if day > 12 !

I've used Eloquent mutators in User model like this :

```
public function getBirthdateAttribute() {
    return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($this->attributes['birthdate']));        
}

public function setBirthdateAttribute($value) {              
    $this->attributes['birthdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
}
```

Please what's the matter with my code !?

Comment: Then its a date formating issue

Comment: Please provide sample data for `$data['birthdate']`.

Comment: How is the data entered? With `-` or `/` seperators

Comment: I enter date value like this : dd/mm/YYYY
but it works fine if I enter a date which day<12 !!!

Comment: But the format strtotime understands is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy/mm/dd`, see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
date("Y-d-m", strtotime($data['birthdate']));
```

to:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['birthdate']));
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html

where your should be like this format `dd-mm-yyyy`, and if it like this `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
$date = '22/05/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Same issue .. :/
If i insert for example 01/03/1990 I'll get 03/01/1990
and if 13/01/1990 will be 1970-01-01 ... :(

Comment: `13/01/1990` - that would be the first day of the 13th month in 1990. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: Thank you so much !! it works !! :)))))))
$date = '22/05/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

Answer (score 2):

This is the piece of the [strtotime() manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you need to read and understand

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So because you are using the `/` as a seperator strtotime() is assuming the American date format and getting the day and month parts confused